# Error using Lumiere: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: error-handling, pytorch, package, typeerror

I am following the instructions of [Lumiere Github](https://github.com/lucidrains/lumiere-pytorch), i.e.

```
pip install lumiere-pytorch
```

and

```
import torch
from lumiere_pytorch import MPLumiere

from denoising_diffusion_pytorch import KarrasUnet

karras_unet = KarrasUnet(
    image_size = 256,
    dim = 8,
    channels = 3,
    dim_max = 768
)

lumiere = MPLumiere(
    karras_unet,
    image_size = 256,
    unet_time_kwarg = 'time',
    conv_module_names = [
        'downs.1',
        'ups.1'
    ],
    attn_module_names = [
        'mids.0'
    ],
    upsample_module_names = [
        'ups.1'
    ],
    downsample_module_names = [
        'downs.1'
    ]
)

noised_video = torch.randn(2, 3, 8, 256, 256)
time = torch.ones(2,)

denoised_video = lumiere(noised_video, time = time)

assert noised_video.shape == denoised_video.shape
```

But I have this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unhashable type: 'list'
  File ".\Documents\lumiere_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lumiere_pytorch import MPLumiere
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I did no modify nothing and I just want to know if this kind of error is my fault or the package's fault.